# tensorflow - Input pipeline with multiple TFRecord files + tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch()

Tags: tensorflow, sliding-window, tfrecord

I have multiple `TFRecord` files, which all hold a specific timeframe of my data. Containing data points are consecutive inside each file but are not consecutive across files. As part of my input pipeline, i am using `tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch` in order to process a window of data points as following:

```
filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(data_dir)]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

dataset = dataset.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocessing_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=y + z)) # sliding window
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: prepare_fn(x, y, z))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
```

How can i prevent the window to be spanned across data points from different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to create the batches on each file independently, and [interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) the results:

```
def interleave_fn(filename):
  dataset = dataset.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
  dataset = dataset.map(preprocessing_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
  dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=y + z)) # sliding window

filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(data_dir)]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.interleave(interleave_fn, num_parallel_calls=...)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: prepare_fn(x, y, z))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
```

This is probably more performant as it bypasses the filter step.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using [`tf.Dataset.filter(predicate)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter).

```
filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(data_dir)]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

dataset = dataset.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocessing_fn, num_parallel_calls=6)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=y + z)) # sliding window
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.equal(x['timeframe'][0], x['timeframe'][-1]))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: prepare_fn(x, y, z))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
```